# MongoDB: how to define the response object using $match and $project

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and I'm trying to query the database and get an object like this in response.

```
{
   activity: 'Aerial Yoga',
   participants_12: 10,
   participants_13_15: 10,
   participants_16_18: 10,
   participants_19: 10,
}
```

I will place an image instead of the full json so I can explain how to get the data:
[image]

I can filter but I still don't know how to format the object the DB returns to me. I'm using this query so far:

```
db.applications.aggregate([
    { $match : {application_number:'SL-O2-2017-05-15-000230', 'sport_activity_list.value.0.properties.sport_activity.value':'Aerial Yoga'}},
    { $project : { _id: 0,  "sport_activity_list.value":1,} }
])
```

How can I achieve the result I want? Should I be using $project? I'm using **v3.2.8** of the mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$aggregate` will do this for you.  In the `$project` step you can specify that existing fields should be included or not included with truthy values, but you can also [included computed fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project), of which this is a very simple example:

```
db.applications.aggregate([
  { $match : {application_number:'SL-O2-2017-05-15-000230', 'sport_activity_list.value.0.properties.sport_activity.value':'Aerial Yoga'}},
  { $project : {
    _id: 0, 
    value: '$sport_activity_list.value.0.properties.sport_activity.value',
    participants_12: '$sport_activity_list.value.0.properties.participants_12.value',
    ...
  } }
])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The DB doesn't complain about the query but it looks like it is in an infinite loop because it never returns the result, it is loading forever. I guess it is due to something in the document I store.

Comment: What interface are you using, please?  Is it the MongoDB shell?

Comment: I'm using Studio 3T. I tried in Robomongo and it returns an empty object, the same happens in the mongo shell

Comment: Is it still empty if you remove the `$project` stage?

Comment: Oh, I looking at the screenshot I see that the fields you're after are buried rather deeper too.